# How to develop a predictive model for construction clam management by using IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: watson-studio-desktop

My first question is does IBM Watson Studio software works for developing model to predict construction claim? I mean i have text data and i want the model to analyze my data and predict claims type according to the contract clauses data and score risks from the claim data. On most of the videos that i see they use numeric data instead of text data. My second question is i am not sure which model i have to use for predicting construction claim? I try to use Anomaly node model because it is used to identify outliers and unusual cases in the data and mostly it is used for insurance claim. I try to screenshot and attached the model that i am working on to develop and the CSV data i have but i cant upload it here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which model to select, but depending upon the format of your text data you can either use Text Analytics within Modeler or you can 'encode' your unique string values into numbers in a new field and use that field for modeling.